# How do I create and connect anonymous-DH TLS sockets with Python and securely authenticate over them without possibility of credential forwarding?

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, ssl, diffie-hellman

I am writing a peer-to-peer protocol wherein nodes can connect to each other and the connection should be encrypted using TLS with session keys agreed with Diffie-Hellman exchange. However, using any kind of certificates would be tedious because after a TLS connection is established, each pair of nodes would still have to mutually authenticate using a ECDSA challenge-response protocol (this using a cipher-suite not supported by OpenSSL).

1. How can I use Python standard library `ssl` module to make such a TLS connection that does not require setting up snake-oil certificates given that I can control the `SSLContext` on both client and server?
2. How can I then authenticate using a challenge-response protocol after the TLS handshake has completed, in a way that would exclude the possibility of a [Mallory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) using credential forwarding?

Answer (score 2):

For part 1, one possibility is to use OpenSSL cipher suite with `AECDH` for example `AECDH-AES256-SHA`. For server the code would be

```
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
context.set_ciphers("AECDH-AES256-SHA:@SECLEVEL=0")

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0) as sock:
    sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8443))
    sock.listen(5)
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=True) as ssock:
        conn, addr = ssock.accept()
```

and for client code you can use the following

```
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
context.set_ciphers("AECDH-AES256-SHA:@SECLEVEL=0")
context.check_hostname = False

with socket.create_connection(('localhost', 8443)) as sock:
    with context.wrap_socket(sock) as conn:
        ...
```

Notably, the `:@SECLEVEL=0` needs to be specified for it to work.

For part 2 and the challenge-response protocol, you can use the channel binding function - the return value of

```
conn.get_channel_binding(cb_type='tls-unique')
```

as part of the signed messages in the challenge-response protocol. This is a 96-bit value.

However, the security of this solution is far from perfect. Notably, using the `AECDH` cipher seems to limit the connection to TLS 1.2, and there are [attacks](https://www.mitls.org/pages/attacks/SLOTH) against the `get_channel_binding(cb_type='tls-unique')` that essentially halve the length of the value, i.e. the effective security would be only 48 bits.

In TLS 1.3 there would be option to derive a longer value, namely `get_channel_binding` with type `tls-exporter`, however it is [not currently supported by Python 3 SSL module](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/95366). On the other hand for TLS 1.3 it seems these anonymous Diffie-Hellman cipher suites are no longer a possibility.